# Max analytical function plus windowed ordering is not working as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with status and location, the following is the data. I'd like to get max status partitioned by location using custom ordering. Any idea what needs to change? Right now it is giving only max value, irrespective of the ordering i mentioned.

The custom ordering is 1 > 3 > 2

```
status | location
  1    | 11 
  2    | 11 
  2    | 12 
  3    | 12
  3    | 11
```

Expected result for location 11 : 1
Expected result for location 12 : 3

**Query:**

```
select max(status) over (partition by location order by decode(status, '1',6,'3',5,'2',4,3) 
                         rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) mx from items;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ed9e7e/13

```
create table items
( status varchar2(1), location number(9)
);

insert into items values('1',123);

insert into items values('2',123);

insert into items values('3',123);

insert into items values('4',123);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `first_value()`:

```
select first_value(status) over (partition by location
                                 order by decode(status, '1', 6, '3', 5, '2', 4, 3) 
                                ) mx
from items;
```

I'm not a big fan of `decode()`, but it is a concise way to express what you want.  I prefer `case` expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of issues. Your decode doesn't seem to match up with you are are saying you want. Secondly, I don't think MAX() is the function you want to use because it is returning maximum status without respect to your custom order. Instead you should assign row numbers partitioned by location and ordered by your custom sort order. Then pick all the rows with where row number is 1.

```
create table items
( status varchar2(1), location number(9)
);

insert into items values('1',11);
insert into items values('2',11);
insert into items values('2',12);
insert into items values('3',12);
insert into items values('3',11);

select x.location, x.status
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by location order by decode(status, '1',1,'2',3,'3',2,4)) as rn, 
           status, location from items) x
where x.rn = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0086/1).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that using a simple GROUP BY might prove easier:

```
SELECT LOCATION,
       DECODE(MAX(ORDERING), 6, '1', 5, '3', 4, '2', 3) AS STATUS
  FROM (SELECT LOCATION,
               STATUS AS STATUS,
               DECODE(STATUS, '1', 6, '3', 5, '2', 4, 3) AS ORDERING
          FROM ITEMS)
  GROUP BY LOCATION
  ORDER BY LOCATION
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4deb2814115aab80e7dc5b34490e93f)